# How to implement horizontal scrolling widget with scrollview in ANDROID?

Tags: android

I am a newbie to ANDROID development. I am developing an application wherein i need to show scrolling of widgets in horizontal direction..

I searched on "Android developer website" & other internet resources but could get a proper solution.

As far as i know ScrollView does not support "Horizontal scrolling".I need to implement it in a horizontal way wherein a user an scroll widgets horizontal way [ and I can do corresponding activity when user select any one of widgets] .

I would grateful for any of help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Comment: app widgets don't support HorizontalScrollView